# How I can show a modal window when data is saved

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, symfony-1.4, symfony-forms

I'll like to show a modal window (Twitter Bootstrap Modal Component) when I save some data in Symfony. I use `doctrine:generate-module` task to build the module but doesn't know how to show the window when I click "Save" button and data is saved. Any suggestion?

**EDIT**: changed from doctrine:generate-admin (wrong) to doctrine:generate-module (right)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For each action that save the current object, the generator define [a *flash* message](http://symfony.com/legacy/doc/jobeet/1_4/en/13?orm=Doctrine#chapter_13_user_flashes) with the success message.

You can see them inside the [action template of the generator](http://trac.symfony-project.org/browser/branches/1.4/lib/plugins/sfDoctrinePlugin/data/generator/sfDoctrineModule/admin/parts/processFormAction.php):

```
$this->getUser()->setFlash('notice', $notice);
```

Flashes messages are then displayed inside a template called [`_flashes.php`](http://trac.symfony-project.org/browser/branches/1.4/lib/plugins/sfDoctrinePlugin/data/generator/sfDoctrineModule/admin/template/templates/_flashes.php). If everything went fine, a notice flash is defined in the action and displayed:

```
<div class="notice">[?php echo __($sf_user->getFlash('notice'), array(), 'sf_admin') ?]</div>
```

What you have to do, is to create a file `_flashes.php` inside your template folder and write the javascript to open a bootstrap modal. Something like:

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
    <h3 id="myModalLabel">Modal header</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <p><?php echo __($sf_user->getFlash('notice'), array(), 'sf_admin') ?></p>
  </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#myModal').modal('show')
</script>
```

This case cover only the **notice** message. You will also have to cover the *error* one.

---

**Update:**

Since you are using a Doctrine Generated Module and not a Doctrine Admin Generator, you have to do this in order to use flashes messages:

Inside your action, find the `processForm` and add the notice:

```
protected function processForm(sfWebRequest $request, sfForm $form)
{
    $notice = $form->getObject()->isNew() ? 'The item was created successfully.' : 'The item was updated successfully.';

    $form->bind($request->getParameter($form->getName()), $request->getFiles($form->getName()));
    if ($form->isValid())
    {
        $alumnos = $form->save();

        $this->getUser()->setFlash('notice', $notice);

        $this->redirect('alumnos/new');
        // $this->redirect('alumnos/edit?id=' . $alumnos->getId());
    }
    else
    {
        $this->getUser()->setFlash('error', 'The item has not been saved due to some errors.', false);
    }
}
```

Then you can add the same `_flashes.php` template you created before and include it (in `newSuccess.php`, since you redirect the user to this action after saving your form):

```
<?php include_partial('flashes') ?>
```

Comment: wow!!! you rocks man!! very good reply!! so if I get the whole thing when I click in "Save" button then the modal should appear showing in this case **notice** messages? I'm right? Any way to pass the error message as array or I should create or manage errors from this template?

Comment: The modal will appear after the page is reloaded. And you can copy/paste this model to handle error message as well. Do not forget to test if there is a message otherwise your modal will always appear

Comment: thanks, I check the _flashes.php template and there I found my answers

Comment: I test what you suggest me and didn't work, data was saved but modal never show ups, why?

Comment: no, no JS error, and yes Bootstrap and jQuery are loaded, I get redirected to edit action instantaneously and modal never show ups. I put the template _flashes.php under `/apps/site/modules/alumnos/templates` is that location right? This is the template content: http://pastie.org/6451685

Comment: It seems ok to me: http://jsfiddle.net/7TfAP/ What html render says? Can you find the modal code somewhere? if you are editing a `alumnos` object, then yes, the template is in its right place.

Comment: well I think the problem is here in this function http://pastie.org/6451981 (how I can write piece of code here in comments????) because I'm not redirecting to edit instead I redirect to new, maybe this is the problem, the HTML has nothing about modal

Comment: Oh this is strange, so every time you save an element you are redirected to `/new` ? Anyway, flashes messages are kept for one redirection. So modal should popup inside the new template too (it's inside a partial which is always included)

Comment: well for some reason flash messages aren't keep. By default the function redirect to edit method by I change to new, if I remove the _flashes.php from template directory default messages aren't showed either, any idea?

Comment: So you never seen flashes messages before. Why do you need to be redirected to new instead of coming back on edit ? This is kind of the default behavior. Can you see if flashes template is rendered inside the html? Otherwise, I don't know :-/

Comment: no, I never see it. I test redirecting to edit instead of new and the same happen. No, flashes template isn't rendering inside the HTML :-( ohh this isn't a admin module is just a module built with `doctrine:generate-module` so maybe you're confused, any chance to get this done by using Ajax instead of your solution?

Comment: Oh you confuse me with `doctrine:generate-admin`.. So you should handle the message on your own. I will updated my answer later.

Comment: so in this case wich are your suggestion?

Comment: Ok, I made changes as you suggested but for some reason layout isn't include  because no CSS, JS or something else are included because of that the modal isn't showed, just the HTML is rendered, why?

Comment: Any error inside the rendered html? Do you have the same behavior if you commend the `include_partial('flashes')` line?

Comment: don't worry I found the error and by the way you answer the question right here in StackOverflow :) because I was using `__()` in `_flashes.php` then I have to load helpers from within config settings.yml and write this `standard_helpers:       [Partial, Cache, I18N]`I know that exists some way to load inside the same template but didn't remember and not sure if it's `use('I18N')` or something else

Comment: Hi I'm having a issue related to this same topic, should I open a new question or should I continue here?

Comment: @ReynierPM you should open a new one and say it is related to this one

Comment: ok, I do it it's [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15365852/problems-with-postvalidator-and-modal-window) see if you could help me with this new problem